# Google Tag Manager JavaScript Error trigger not fired before gtm load

Tags: javascript, error-handling, google-tag-manager

I added a JavaScript Error trigger in GTM, and obviously it won't fired in the page before gtm loads. I wonder how can I catch those errors, e.g. I have below script before gtm loads

```
<script> 
    undefinedObject.undefinedMethod(); 
</script>
// I can see error in browser console but GTM because this error occurs before GTM loads.
```

I tried to overwrite `window.onerror` function at the very beginning with pushing error event to `dataLayer`

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
                    
    var event = {
        'event': "gtm.pageError",
        'gtm.errorLineNumber': lineNo,
        'gtm.errorMessage': msg,
        'gtm.errorUrl': url,
        'gtm.uniqueEventId': dataLayer.length+1
    }

    dataLayer.push(event);
    
    return false;
}
```

It does capture the error as the event is already in `dataLayer` when gtm initialize, but then after gtm loaded, any errors come later will be pushed to `dataLayer` TWICE as I overwrite the default `window.onerror` and gtm overwrite again when it loads

```
// window.onerror definition in GTM source file
ƒ (d,e,f,h,k){
    c&&c(d,e,f,h,k); // this should be running the default `window.onerror` which I edited previously
    Um({             // then GTM do it again
    event:"gtm.pageError",
    "gtm.errorMessage":d,
    "gtm.errorUrl":e,
    "gtm.errorLineNumber":f
    });
    return!1
}
```

So,
what is the correct way to capture JS Error with GTM? without logging every errors twice or be able to capture error before gtm loads. Thank you so much.

Comment: No tested, so a comment rather than an answer, but you could wrap the push into a conditional where you check if the google_tag_manager object exists, and push only when it doesn't.  That should prevent your customized push once GTM is instantiated.

Comment: Thank @EikePierstorff, followed your suggestion and it works.